# Alfresco error Web Script Status 500 - Internal Error Web

Tags: java, drupal-7, alfresco, cmis, alfresco-share

I am new to Drupal. I am configuring Drupal and Alfresco using CMIS. I am able to see the files and folders of Alfresco in Drupal. I am not able to retrieve those files using the cmis queries for example`SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE cmis:objectId='workspace://SpacesStore/d3c5f86e-9174-4cfb-9bc9-03aa881d0810'`.. I am getting the following error log:

```
HTTP call to [http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/queries] returned [500]. 
Response: Web Script Status 500 - Internal Error Web Script Status 500 - Internal Error The Web Script /alfresco/service/cmis/queries has responded with a status of 500 - Internal Error. 500 
Description: An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request.
Message:00300034 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 00300212 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js': 00300211
Exception:java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException - NotAfter: Fri Aug 17 17:34:11 IST 2012
sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity.valid(CertificateValidity.java:256) 
sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(X509CertImpl.java:570) 
sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifyTimestamp(BasicChecker.java:157) 
sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:109) 
sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:117) 
sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.doValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:328) 
sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:178) 
java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:250) 
sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:275) 
sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:263) 
sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:173) 
sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218) 
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126) 
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209) 
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249) 
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1185) 
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:136) 
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593) 
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529) 
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:893) 
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1138) 
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:632) 
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:59) 
java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65) 
java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123) 
org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:506) 
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114) 
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096) 
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398) 
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171) 
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397) 
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323) 
org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:318) 
org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryLanguage.executeQuery(SolrQueryLanguage.java:49) 
org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrCMISQueryServiceImpl.query(SolrCMISQueryServiceImpl.java:93) 
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor860.invoke(Unknown Source) 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:65) 
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) 
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) 
$Proxy140.query(Unknown Source) 
org.alfresco.repo.cmis.rest.CMISScript.query(CMISScript.java:683) 
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor859.invoke(Unknown Source) 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:155) 
org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:243) 
org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:76) 
org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c13._c0(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js:67) 
org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c13.call(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js) 
org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:393) 
org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2834) 
org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c13.call(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js) 
org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c13.exec(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js) 
org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:483) 
org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:191) 
org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.execute(ScriptServiceImpl.java:212) 
org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.executeScript(ScriptServiceImpl.java:174) 
org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryScriptProcessor.executeScript(RepositoryScriptProcessor.java:102) 
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.executeScript(AbstractWebScript.java:1193) 
org.alfresco.repo.cmis.rest.CMISWebScript.executeScript(CMISWebScript.java:46) 
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:86) 
org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$2.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:393) 
org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:388) 
org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:462) 
org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:500) 
org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:316) 
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:372) 
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209) 
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:118) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:58) 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) 
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470) 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) 
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) 
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298) 
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:861) 
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579) 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1584) 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) &nbsp;
Exception:java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException - timestamp check failed
sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:139)
Exception:sun.security.validator.ValidatorException - PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:289)
Exception:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException - sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
Exception:org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.lucene.LuceneQueryParserException - 00300211
org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:364)
Exception:org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException - 00300212 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js': 00300211
org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:195)
Exception:org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException - 00300034 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 00300212 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js': 00300211
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:970)
Server:Community v4.0.0 (4003) schema 5,025 Time:30 Jan, 2013 12:52:18 PM
Diagnostics:Inspect Web Script (org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post)
Error returning CMIS results - check your repository is active and the query / path is correct
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Ramsus said, it's a problem with your Solr configuration. Even if you're not directly calling Solr, you're running a CMIS query, which is internally routed by Alfresco to the search engine, i.e. Solr. It should be pretty evident from the stack trace you posted:

```
org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHTTPClient.executeQuery(SolrQueryHTTPClient.java:318) 
org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryLanguage.executeQuery(SolrQueryLanguage.java:49) 
org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrCMISQueryServiceImpl.query(SolrCMISQueryServiceImpl.java:93) 
[...]    
org.alfresco.repo.cmis.rest.CMISScript.query(CMISScript.java:683)
```

That said, the main issue is about HTTPS and certificate validation, which fails because of an expired certificate:

```
Exception:java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException - NotAfter: Fri Aug 17 17:34:11 IST 2012
sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity.valid(CertificateValidity.java:256)
```

You need to use a valid certificate for the HTTPS communication between Alfresco and Solr.

EDIT: As per @Will Abson comment, it's a [known issue](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/announcements/important-ssl-certs-solr-alfresco-4-expire-week-08152012-1307) of the out of the box SSL certificate. You need to create or retrieve another valid one and configure it as described in the [wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_And_SOLR#Generating_new_SSL_certificates)

Comment: Yup, looks like this issue - https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/announcements/important-ssl-certs-solr-alfresco-4-expire-week-08152012-1307

Answer (score 0):

...
Exception:java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException - NotAfter: Fri Aug 17 17:34:11 IST 2012
....

Probably the Alfresco Solr certificate - see http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_And_SOLR

Comment: @Rasmas thanks for the reply.. I think i don't need to use solr because the error is coming in drupal view..Any other suggestion

Comment: You either need to disable Solr indexing and use Lucene instead OR fix the problem (as per https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/announcements/important-ssl-certs-solr-alfresco-4-expire-week-08152012-1307).